# Two Dimensional Array init in C++11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

## I'm trying to get full understandig of C++ arrays init.

Here is the code snippet:

```
int main() {
    const int n= 20;
    int m;
    m = n+10;
    int (*a)[m] = new int [n][m]; //1
    int *w = new int [m]; //2
    int (*b)[n] = new int [m][n]; //3
    int (*d)[n] = new int [n][n]; //4
}
```

If i'll try to comple this code, i'll get the errors:

```
error: array size in new-expression must be constant
error: the value of 'm' is not usable in a constant expression
note: 'int m' is not const
```

I have read, that for array init variable must to be a **const**, but, if so, then i have some questions:

1. Why is it possible to init single-dimensional array **(2)** using non-const variable **m**?
2. Why is it possible to init two-dimensional array **(3)** using non-const variable **m** at rows number position?
3. Why isn't possible to init two-dimensional array **(1)** using non-const variable **m** at column number position?

Just in case, I'll clarify, that i'm not looking for workarounds, another ways, etc. Just for theoretical knowledge.

Thank you!

Comment: C++ does not support C variable length arrays, so you can't use them in C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `a` point to a (one-dimensional) array allocated with `new T[n];` for some type `T`.

When accessing the `i`-th array element, as in `a[i]`, or even when computing its address, as in `a+i`, the compiler must compute the *offset*, i.e. how many bytes there are between the first byte in the array and the first byte in its `i`-th element.

Such as offset is then computed as `i * sizeof(T)`. This multiplication can be made more efficient if `sizeof(T)` is a constant which is statically known, i.e. known at compile-time. For this reason, it makes sense to forbid those types `T` whose size can not be statically predicted. ISO C++ follows this path.

Note that the size of the array (`n`) is irrelevant here, since it does not affect the offset computation. The size `n` can be freely computed at run-time. We only care about `sizeof(T)` being statically known.

Now, some good news: for most types `T` we can indeed compute `sizeof(T)` at compile-time. If `T` is a numeric type or a pointer we know its size. If it's a class and we know the `sizeof` of all the members, we also know the size of the class (which will be their sum, plus some padding).

However, what if `T` is an array type itself? What if `T = U[m]` for some type `U`? Well, here we need to statically know both `sizeof(T)` and the value of `m`. This is the key point.

Note that in this case, `a = new T[n]` is actually meaning `a = new U[n][m]`
(no, it's not `U[m][n]` -- the syntax can be confusing): `T[n]` is an array of `n` values of type `T`, and `U[n][m]` is an array of `n` values of type array of `m` values of type `U`, which is the same.

Finally, we can sum everything up: in `new U[n][m]`, `n` can be freely computed at run-time, but `m` must be known at compile-time.

This generalizes to multi-dimensional arrays: all dimensions except the first one must be statically known.

Some compilers implement a non-standard (non-ISO C++) extension that allows `m` to be computed at run-time, even if that slows down the computation of the offset. This is called "VLA" (variable-length arrays). Usually there's also a compiler flag to turn it off (`-pedantic`) so that one does not inadvertently use it.